# Functions With Global Inputs Return NaN

Tags: javascript, function, methods, return, nan

**Edit:**

I wanted to be more specific about why I'm doing it this way.  The code below is something I've been attempting to get working.

```
function newClass(self) {
    this.invest;
    this.interest;
    function method1() {
        return this.invest + this.interest;
    }
}
var newC = new newClass();
newC.invest = prompt("Enter investment");
newC.interest = prompt("Enter interest");
alert(newC.method1());
```

**End Of Edit:**

I'm fairly new to the javascript language and can not figure out why my functions are always returning NaN.  I have attempted many different fixes but nothing I have tried works.  Below is an example.

```
function investment() {
    var iniInvest;
    var interest;
    return iniInvest + interest;
}

investment.iniInvest = 10;
investment.interest = 20;  
console.log(investment())
```

This returns a NaN. I have attempted creating classes and methods and attempted to parse the variables but they still all return NaN.

Unless the variables values are assigned to the var in the function

```
var iniInvest = 10;
```

or args are given

```
function investment(args1, args2) {
    return args1 + args2;
}
console.log(investment(10, 20));
```

it will return NaN.

I appreciate the help.

Comment: Passing the arguments is the  way to go. When you assign values like `investment.iniInvest` it is assigning them to the function object. To access them in the function you would need to use `investment.iniInvest + investment.interest` which is kind of silly. A quick review of javascript scope will clear up a lot of confusion.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access the variable inside functions like

```
investment.iniInvest = 10;
investment.interest = 20;
```

Since, you need that variables globally accessed so you can keep that variables outside the function and initialize them from anywhere in the code:

```js
var iniInvest;
var interest;
function investment() {
    return iniInvest + interest;
}
iniInvest = 10;
interest = 20;
console.log(investment())
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when you declare a variable inside of a function, it exists only within that function, and is only local. Therefore, it can not be referenced from outside of the function.

In the example that you gave, you attempt to reference the variable `investment.iniInvest` and `investment.interest`, but those variables only exist within the local reference of the investment function, and are destroyed after the function ends, so you can not reference them. You're probably better off using args anyways.

Answer (score 0):

The code `investment.iniInvest = 10;` is creating an `iniInvest` property on investment, not a local variable. This code does not modify the variable `var iniInvest` created within the function's scope.

```
function investment() {
    return investment.iniInvest + investment.interest;
}

investment.iniInvest = 10;
investment.interest = 20;  
console.log(investment())
```

This code achieves what you are asking, but this is not a good way to solve the problem.

The following is more likely what you are looking for:

```js
function investment( iniInvest, interest) {
  this.iniInvest = iniInvest;
  this.interest = interest;
  this.investment = function() {
    return this.iniInvest + this.interest;
  };
}
    
var inv = new investment( 10, 30 );
console.log( inv.investment() );
inv.iniInvest = 5;
inv.interest = 10;
console.log( inv.investment() );
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are declaring `iniInvest` `interest` in function so you can not use that variable out of that function as they are out of scope. Make that variable global.
You can go through https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp for scope of variables.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like

```
var investment = function () {
    this.iniInvest;
    this.interest;
    this.sum = function() {
        return this.iniInvest + this.interest;
    }
}
var i = new investment()
i.iniInvest = 10;
i.interest = 20;  
console.log(i.sum());
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for all your answers!  After reading everyones answer I was able to fix my syntax and resolve the problem.

This is my finished code.

```
function newClass() {
    this.invest;
    this.interest;
        this.investment = function() {
            return parseFloat(this.invest) + parseFloat(this.interest);
        }
    }
    var newC = new newClass();
    newC.invest = prompt("Enter investment");
    newC.interest = prompt("Enter interest");
    alert(newC.investment());
```

It returns the proper answer.  Please do let me know if this code requires fixing.

Thanks Again!